# Onclick Send Event JS Being Removed From Template When Rendering

Tags: javascript, algolia

I've added an onclick event to the hits item template but when it renders the onclick JS is missing.  It seems to be getting stripped as the rest of the button renders correctly.

```
instantsearch.widgets.hits({
    container: "#hits",
    templates: {
        item: (hit, { html, sendEvent }) => html`
            <div class="product" data-id="${hit.objectID}">
                <a href="${hit.url}">
                    <img
                        src="${hit.thumbnail
                            ? hit.thumbnail
                            : "/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce-placeholder-150x150.png"}"
                        align="left"
                        alt="${hit.title}"
                    />
                </a>
                <div class="hit-name">
                    <h4>${hit.title}</h4>
                    <p>${hit.content}</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary"
                        onclick="${() =>
                            sendEvent("click", hit, "my-click-event")}"
                    >
                        Click event
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        `,
        empty: "<div>No results have been found for {{ query }}</div>",
    },
}),
```

Any ideas why it's removing my JS?

Comment: I think `onclick` should be camel cased like `onClick`?  also you should not use nested double quotes `"`.
So try change from `onclick="${() => sendEvent("click", hit, "my-click-event")}"` to `onClick="${() => sendEvent('click', hit, 'my-click-event')}"`?

Comment: @Ravikumar HTML5 is not case sensitive, so you an use onClick, ONLICK or whatever combo you want.  Single or double quotes make no difference, JS is still stripped out.

Comment: ahh sorry, yeah you are correct. I thought it was similar like JSX but it's template string(tagFunction).

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/algolia/doc-code-samples/tree/master/instantsearch.js/algolia-insights?file=/src/app.js it seems to do the job as i can see a network request going when clicked

Comment: it attaches an event listener. you can see it in event listener tab

Comment: @cmgchess yes you are right :)  Why does the onClick JS it get removed from the button HTML?

Comment: @AndrewSchultz maybe the template engine does a button.addEventListener in js so that's why it is not showing in the HTML?

Comment: @cmgchess makes sense, would keep the HTML cleaner that way.  I can see the event handler attached on my localhost but it doesn't fire any network requests.  It might be something to do with running the code on my localhost... I don't see any kind of errors in the console though...

Comment: have you set `insights: true` when initializing search. maybe you can try with something random like `onclick="${() => console.log(hit)}"` and see if logs on console

Comment: @cmgchess yes insights are set, I'll try a console log. Thanks.

Comment: @cmgchess tried a console log and it worked.  Next thing I'm going to try is using the CDN hosted files instead of locally hosted for Algolia see if that makes any difference...

Comment: @cmgchess you won't believe this but it works when I use the hosted Algolia JS files but not when I load them locally.... Need to work out the difference now...

Comment: i couldnt test it locally sorry so i have no clue

Comment: @cmgchess no worries, thanks for lending your ear to help me get to the bottom of this :)

Comment: hope you find the solution. good luck